# AngualrJs Material Design phonegap project working on iOS and Windows Phone

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8, material-design

We have an Angularjs Material design phonegap application, which is not working in iOS and Windows Phone. It just gives blank screen. Did anybody had success with it? What are the tricks to get it to work?

Comment: do you have any result?

Comment: Yes... sorry, should have updated once we fixed it. The very first screen was loading angularjs and other libraries after binding the model. We started loading the libraries and dependencies before the binding screens, and it started working in iOS and Windows Phone. Strangely Android never complained.